# Are there upper bounds on the worst case complexity of NP-complete problems?

Tags: upper-bounds, np-complete

I have proven some problem to be (weakly) NP-complete and try to find out some algorithm to solve it exactly. Except for some pseudo-polynomial stuff, I would be happy with an algorithm running in $O(c^n)$ for a constant $c$, but the best algorithm I can imagine runs in $O(n!)$, so much worse. Since all other NP-complete problems, where I know an exact algorithm, can be solved in exponential time, the question that comes to my mind is if there is some upper bound on the complexity of NP-complete problems like $O(c^n)$ or if there are problems with a proven lower bound of something like $O(n!)$, too (unless P = NP). At least everything is reducible to SAT, which in turn can be solved in $O(2^n)$.

Comment: Have you tried "generate a possible solution then check it in polynomial time"?

Comment: Note that $n!=2^{O(n \log(n))}$, so it is not much worse than $c^n$.

Comment: Also, if the reduction from your problem to SAT takes linear time, then your problem can be solved in $c^n$ time.

Comment: The upper bound on NP is $2^{n^{O(1)}}$ which is called exponential.

Comment: Note that $n!=2^{\Omega(n\log n)}$, so it is quite a bit worse than $c^n$.

Comment: there must be some way to show that conditional on the ETH there exist problems in NP that take time at least $2^{n^c}$ for an infinite sequence of integers $c$. on the other hand $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$ as far as I know could be consistent with $\mathsf{NP} \subseteq \mathsf{DTIME}(n^{\log^* n})$

Comment: @Sasho: "given an NTM $M$ and a unary number $n$, does $M$ halt in $n^c$ steps?"

Comment: Why don't you ask a question where you describe your specific problem?